# New ADT 23.0.6 in android.com for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I know that now, official Android IDE is Android Studio, but I say that in March 2015 android released new ADT for Eclipse. 
What is the story here? What features were added to ADT 23.0.6?
I am new in Android, and I was learning android with Android Studio, but it was so complicated and was presenting new concepts that I preferred to begin with Eclipse. Well, Applications were written by Eclipse are still working, so  I was happy that I saw new ADT for Eclipse in Android.com, however, I don't know still what can we do with new ADT, do I still need to learn Android Studio or I should hope that Eclipse is still considered major IDE for Android?
Thanks :)

Comment: "do I still need to learn Android Studio" yes, it is the official IDE for android development, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Android Studio it's now the official Android IDE and it will stay like this for a while I think you should cope with it. 
Personally, I also like Eclipse more but I guess I will slowly make my way to the new official IDE.
Eclipse for android development it's not dead yet but it will be less and less used for this purpose and so I think you should really learn Android Studio.

Comment: Since most application should support former APIs, is it really a necessity to immigrate to Android Studio? API 8 is still API 8, either with Android Studio or with Eclipse.
However, what about new ADT? I believe many have not immigrated to Android Studio so Eclipse is still the major IDE

Comment: There are for sure many developers still using Eclipse and ADT release was a necesity. But the majority is immigrating to Android Studio and the documentation/support comes with priority for Android Studio. ATM Eclipse it's still viable but it's better to change soon than late.